# Дописать строки в файл

Tags: c#, .net

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос, как дописать в новый образовавшийся файл текст, в определённые строки, например,  в первую строку и т.п.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;   

public class FailR
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Path = @"C:\Users\Desktop\1\1.MST";
        string Paths = @"C:\Users\Desktop\1\01.xml";

        int Stroka = 9;

        string[] AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(Path);

        using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(Paths))

        for (int i = Stroka; i < AllLines.Length; i++)
            {
                s.WriteLine(AllLines[i].Replace(".", "255 ").Replace("X", "002 ").Replace("1", "001 ").Insert(0, "<Row><![CDATA[ ").Insert(202, " ]]></Row>"));
            }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Никак.

Вы не можете дописать в середину текстового файла. Читайте файл построчно, выводите информацию в другой файл, потом удаляйте старый файл и переименовывайте новый.

Или считайте весь файл в память, модифицируйте и запишите назад (если файл небольшой).

---

Если у вас уже читается весь документ в память, проблем нет. Проверяйте индекс текущей строки и модифицируйте, если надо, перед выводом.